# Typical memory usage for Django applications

Tags: python, django, memory-management, celery

I am deploying a Django application (DEBUG=False) on an Ubuntu server and I am seeing high memory consumption by gunicorn and celery processes.

```
Processes   User       Count    CPU Memory
-------------------------------------------
gunicorn    www-data    3   0.5%    193 MB
celery      celery      2   0.3%    121 MB
celery      root        1   0.0%    44.9 MB
rsyslogd    syslog      1   0.0%    31.3 MB
postgres    postgres    6   0.0%    26.5 MB
```

It is a pretty small application (~400 db rows) and there is no traffic to the website yet.
The snapshot was taken just after power-cyclying the server.

I am trying to understand, is this memory consumption *normal*?
What are the typical memory usages I should expect for an idle system?

There are some [blogs](http://chase-seibert.github.io/blog/2013/08/03/diagnosing-memory-leaks-python.html) about memory leaks in python, but for an idle system, that might not be such a big issue.

Comment: i have a rather small app running and uwsgi takes up about 40mb per process and i start 4 of them: so inline with your gunicorn process.

Comment: For celery you might want to use the concurrency option  `--concurrency=1`  .  (but still, it should not use that much memory, is there some heavy processing going on in your scheduled tasks?)

Comment: @warath-coder Just curious, what sort of concurrency are four workers able to provide? Is it really just 4 parallel requests and if there's a fifth one is has to wait? How are the performance numbers, roughly? I'm just trying to get a sense of Django's performance. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

Normally for a typical Django Application it would take 60 - 80 MB for a Django app with database connections, for a Django app which only requires a little bit of database connections, only takes up about 18 MB memory. For a more sophisticated Django app which requires queueing up tasks, send emails, database connections, user logins, etc, it would require about 130 MB. and yes Celery consumes a lot of memory, you could try using eventlet to reduce the memory consumption: Here's [a link](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/concurrency/eventlet.html)

Comment: Thank you a lot for these information.. Would you please share a reference? I'd like to learn more details about that.